# Is there a significant difference between French press coffee and Moka pot coffee?

Tags: coffee

Assuming they are from the same bean, is there a significant difference between the two? How would it be best described?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is a significant difference between the two. I would put them at pretty close to opposite ends of the coffee spectrum.

French Press: Generally made with a coarse grind, longer steeping time. Result is a weaker (less concentrated) more typical American style coffee. This will likely be consumed in the same way as a typical filtered, drip coffee would.

Moka Pot: Made with a much finer grind. And while many will argue it's not true espresso. It is much closer to being an espresso. I don't really care what you call it, but it'll be a much stronger more robust coffee. The same amount of coffee will be extracted to a smaller quantity of water. This would be consumed in the same way as an espresso would. You can water it down to make an Americano, etc...

Comment: What is "a straight coffee"?

Comment: I would imagine that what talon8 meant by "straight coffee" is filter coffee.

Comment: Edited for clarity.